# get numbers after the last occurance of alphabet from string using php regex

Tags: php, regex

i have sequence of strings in excel file.

```
example:

1780CAR405108CCC72 

1780CAR405108KK89.0

1780CAR405108B7888
```

I need to get the numbers/floats whatever after the last occurrence of an ALPHABET
like in these examples above, after CCC or KK or B. need assistance asap....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('#[^a-zA-Z]+$#', $string, $result);
```

Comment: worked for both digits and floats etc. thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z]([\d\.]+?)$
```

lazy match anchored at the end of the string, matches digits and fullstops into a capture group.

Also, since you're using PHP, you can use this if you don't want to deal with capture groups:

```
(?<=[^\d])[\d\.]+?$
```

Comment: Habit more than anything else

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

`[^a-zA-Z]` is a negated character class, it stands for "one character, any character but the ones inside the class". `$` matches the end of the string.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/qI1xP9).

Using [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]+$/', "1780CAR405108B72", $match);
print($match);
```

Comment: preg_match('[^a-zA-Z]+$', "1780CAR405108B72") how to use it?

Comment: @user3118004: edited with code sample. On the regex101 link I gave there's also a code generator (middle left) btw

Comment: your solution misses if its float.

Comment: @user3118004: I forgot the regex delimiters in the php code (edited now), but it has nothing to do with floats. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

$matches will contain numbers/float after alphabets.

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]+$/', "1780CAR405108B72",$matches);
```

'/pattern/'==> where slash is the delimiter.